# Duals of Hilbert Subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

So I am confused about something very basic. I'm going to outline my confusion, and would love if someone could point out when I'm saying something wrong.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. It's dual $H^*$ can be identified with $H$ by Reisz representation theorem. Now let $A$ be a closed subspace. $A$ is then a Hilbert space in its own right, and so it's dual $A^*$ can be identified with $A$ again by Reisz representation. Therefore we have a canonical injection $i: A^* \rightarrow H^*$.

On the other hand to every element in $H^*$, say $\phi$, we can consider the restriction $\phi|_A$ as a bounded linear operator on $A$, and so $\phi|_A \in A^*$. Therefore, I have created a map $j: H^* \rightarrow A^*$.

In finite dimensions, it is clear $j$ is not injective just by considering $H = R^n, A = R^k, k < n$. So the right way to think about this is that as the space gets higher in dimension the dual space also gets higher in dimension.

However, when dealing with infinite dimensional spaces like $H^s, L2,$ etc... I am used to thinking that as the space shrinks the dual space grows. For instance in PDE we freely use the fact that $H_0^1 \subset L2 \Rightarrow H^{-1} \supset L2^* = L2$   How do I reconcile these two points of view? Is there something strange with regards to considering consistent inner products?

Comment: $H_0^1$ is not a _subspace_ of $L^2$. It has a strictly finer topology. _That_ makes the dual grow. A proper closed subspace of $L^2$ in its subspace topology has its dual naturally embedded in the dual of $L^2$ as the annihilator of its orthogonal complement [which, with the Riesz identification, corresponds to the subspace itself].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different situations. In the first one, you have a Banach space $X$ and a closed subspace $V$ equipped with the *same* norm. Then, one knows that $V^* \cong X^* / V^\perp$ (that is, take the quotient space w.r.t. the annihilator of $V$). In some sense, $X^*/V^\perp$ is smaller than $X^*$. Note that in the Hilbert space setting, $X^*/V^\perp$ can be identified with a subspace of $X^*$.

In the second situation, you have a Banach space $X$ and a dense subspace $V$. $V$ is equipped with a stronger norm, such that it becomes also a Banach space. In this situation you get $X^* \subset V^*$ (can be proven by using Hahn-Banach).